# Connecting Indicator LEDs to Arduino Pro Mini

Tags: led, xbee, arduino-pro-mini, voltage-level

I'm new to electronics and unsure whether my design below will work as intended. XBee Series 2 and Arduino Pro Mini 5V are used. There are 4 LEDs, each with the following roles:

1. `LED1`: Flicker when transferring data to XBee
2. `LED2`: Flicker when transferring data to Arduino
3. `LED3`: Turns on when XBee is powered on
4. `LED4`: Turns on when Arduino is powered on

[image]

Also, will it suffice to use 3.3V LEDs for `LED1`, `LED2`, `LED3` and 5V LEDs for `LED4`?

Comment: They will all fail to work. Consider fooling around with LEDs separate from a MCU first.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is it because I left out a resistor in series with the LEDs?

Comment: That's one of them. The other is that current doesn't flow that way through a diode.

Comment: Oops I need to flip them around

Comment: The new schematic looks fine now. You can use any led you want, but you have to [calculate the correct resistor value](http://led.linear1.org/1led.wiz) for them, so they don't burn out. Or you can be lazy and just use a 1000 Ohm resistor; the led will be less bright, but as it's only used as an indicator that doesn't matter so much.

Comment: Note that the LEDs on the UART might not work how you desire them to, and that I have no idea what DIO9 does.

Comment: @Gerben I notice that there are no 5V surface mount LEDs (0603 or similar) on Digikey/Mouser, am I checking under the wrong categories?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Looks like I should connect LED3 to pin 1 instead... I was hoping the UART LEDs will flicker like on the Arduino Uno

Comment: There's no such thing as a "5V LED". You take the Vf of the LED you have, and then you calculate the resistance required to drop the rest of the voltage with the desired current.